# Scanner not being used when trying to run something that its implemented in

Tags: java

So I'm trying to use the scanner to fill an array i have it correctly set up and when i run the program it lets me fill the first array and then the second array just gets completely skipped over for the scanner part. I have tried many things and have concluded that its something to do with having 2 scanners together. I expect to enter the overall record which it lets me then enter the division record but it doesn't let me enter any values for it. If you are trying to run it case sensitivity does not matter and to enter the data it should be done with something separating the numbers like a space, comma, or a dash.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TeamInfo {

    public static String[] teamsAFC = {"Ravens", "Bills", "Bengals", "Browns", "Broncos", 
            "Texans", "Colts", "Jaguars", "Chiefs", "Chargers", "Dolphins", "Patriots", "Jets", 
            "Raiders", "Steelers", "Titans"};

    public static String[] teamsNFC = {"Cardinals", "Falcons", "Panthers", "Bears", "Cowboys", 
            "Lions", "Packers", "Rams", "Vikings", "Saints", "Giants", "Eagles", "49ers", 
            "Seahawks", "Buccaneers", "Redskins"};

    private static String conference, team;
    public static int[] overall = new int[3];
    public static int[] division = new int[3];

    public static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    public TeamInfo() {

    }

    public static void teamPick() {
        do {
            System.out.print("Pick an NFL Confrence (AFC/NFC): ");
            conference = kb.next();

            if (conference.toUpperCase().equals("AFC")) {
                for(int i = 0; i < teamsAFC.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(teamsAFC[i]);
                }
            }
            else if (conference.toUpperCase().equals("NFC")) {
                for(int i = 0; i < teamsNFC.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(teamsNFC[i]);
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input please try again......");
            }
        } while (!conference.toUpperCase().equals("AFC") && !conference.toUpperCase().equals("NFC"));

        System.out.print("Pick a team from the list: ");
        team = kb.next();   
    }

    public static void overall() {
        System.out.print("Enter the teams overall record(include ties): ");
        while (!kb.hasNext()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < overall.length; i++) {
                overall[i] = kb.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void division() {
        System.out.print("Enter the teams division record(include ties): ");
        while (!kb.hasNext()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < division.length; i++) {
                division[i] = kb.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void finalOutput() {
        System.out.println("\t" + team.toUpperCase());
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        teamPick();
        overall();
        division();
        finalOutput();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the while loops in both the `overall()` and the `division()` methods should solve your problem.

The reason you could only enter the `overall()` input is because when you try to call `!kb.hasNext()`, it only evaluates to true for the last input in the `teamPick()` method. So once you enter a new value, then `!kb.hasNext()` becomes false and that's why it wouldn't allow you to enter input for the division method.